# Print a single word from a string when identified

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am new to python and programming and have been trying to teach myself with this project.

The below codes runs with out error, but it creates an empty .csv.

I thought I could use a `words = text.split()`, but I can't do that with a generator.

Here is a sample of the data I get:

```
Wed Dec 11 22:51:56 +0000 2013,@KBIJR please contact me via email: 37four@gmail.com...thanks!,1260080780
```

I just want to print email address from the 'text' string in my .csv.

```
import csv
import json
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib
import sys
import requests
import time

CONSUMER_KEY = ""
CONSUMER_SECRET = ""
ACCESS_KEY = ""
ACCESS_SECRET = ""

class TwitterSearch:
    def __init__(self,
        ckey    = CONSUMER_KEY,
        csecret = CONSUMER_SECRET,
        akey    = ACCESS_KEY,
        asecret = ACCESS_SECRET,
        query   = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.{mode}?{query}'
    ):
        consumer     = oauth.Consumer(key=ckey, secret=csecret)
        access_token = oauth.Token(key=akey, secret=asecret)
        self.client  = oauth.Client(consumer, access_token)
        self.query   = query

    def search(self, q, mode='json', **queryargs):
        queryargs['q'] = q
        query = urllib.urlencode(queryargs)
        return self.client.request(self.query.format(query=query, mode=mode))

def write_csv(fname, rows, header=None, append=False, **kwargs):
    filemode = 'ab' if append else 'wb'
    with open(fname, filemode) as outf:
        out_csv = csv.writer(outf, **kwargs)
        if header:
            out_csv.writerow(header)
        out_csv.writerows(rows)

def main():
    ts = TwitterSearch()
    response, data = ts.search('@gmail.com', result_type='recent')
    js = json.loads(data)

    messages = ([msg['created_at'], msg['text'], msg['user']['id']] for msg in js.get('statuses', []))

    search_terms = ['@gmail.com']
    text = messages
    matches = []
    for term in search_terms:
        match = [word for word in text if term in word]
        matches.append(match)   
        write_csv('twitter_gmail.csv', messages, append=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you sure that your string literals are correct? CONSUMER_KEY appears to lack a closing `"`.

Comment: First off you do nothing with the matches variable.

Comment: The logic is definitely confusing. For each term in search terms you update the CSV with the same messages, no changes made. So the CSV has multiple copies of the message with no way to differentiate why each row is present? You also do not check that ts.search() worked and that js actually contains json data. text is messages which is a list of lists which will never match search_terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is extract emails from text strings:

```
import re

s = "Wed Dec 11 22:51:56 +0000 2013,@KBIJR please contact me via email: 37four@gmail.com...thanks!,1260080780"

match_emails = re.compile((
    "([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`"
    "{|}~-]+)*(@|\sat\s)(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.|"
    "\sdot\s))+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)")
)

emails = match_emails.findall(s)
for email in emails:
    print email[0]
```

**Output:**

```
37four@gmail.com
```

Comment: Can you imagine what would happen if that regex had an error in it?

Comment: The world would blow up :)

Comment: This did work but I ended up dumping the data into Mysql and using a substring query to extract it out since I needed the data in a table anyway..  Thank you!  Love this site